# R - networkD3 - forceNetwork - node shape

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3

Is there a way to change the node shape based on a column in nodeList, so that we have different node shapes [rect, sqr, tri] according to row value instead of the default circle.

MWE from documentation:

```
library(networkD3)
# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
            Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
            Group = "group", opacity = 0.4,
            colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);"))
```

Comment: At the moment, no. It would conflict with the interactive features. I have a dev version working offline that allows you to select any of the standard svg shapes, but haven’t had time to polish it up for a release.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to it. I wish I could say let me know if I can help. :D

Comment: `networkD3` is open source and easy to get involved here: https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3

Comment: @CJYetman has this feature been added since this post? Do you know how I could change the shapes of the nodes with the forceNetwork function? I'm using it in my Shiny application and would rather keep using the same library.

Comment: No. The maintainer with admin hasn't touched it in years.

Answer (score 0):

Node shapes can be defined using the `visNetwork` package:

```
library(visNetwork)
data(MisLinks, package="networkD3")
names(MisLinks) <- c("from","to","value")

data(MisNodes, package="networkD3")
MisNodes$id <- 0:(nrow(MisNodes)-1)

# Set of available node shapes 
shapes <- c("square", "triangle", "box", "circle", "dot", "star",
            "ellipse", "database", "text", "diamond")
# Define a column of node shapes
set.seed(1)
MisNodes$shape <- sample(shapes, nrow(MisNodes), replace=T)

visNetwork(nodes=MisNodes, edges=MisLinks)
```

[image]

Comment: I know about `visNetwork`. My shiny app is using `networkD3` for all networks. I was asking to keep consistency